# How to connect points layer with another points layer like in Neural Network Model?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to recreate this neural network model in Blender using *Geometry Nodes* as follows:

[image]
[image]

I have created random points on the plane, now I need to create connections where each point needs to be connected to each front point in the parallel point plane (as shown in the neural network simulation grid screenshot).

[image]

This is the node tree:

[image]

Do you have any suggestions?

Here is the Blend file:

[image]

Comment: I think you would increase your chances of getting help with this dramatically if you shared the .blend file. You can use [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) to do that.

Comment: Added Blend file to the question.

Comment: Perfect, but I'm honestly not clear what is supposed to be connected to what here (the image you show here is quite small). Can you explain this a little more?

Comment: Added more explanation in description and two screenshot of AI Neural Network model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this task like this:

[image]

Here I simply duplicate the points of the mesh with `Duplicate Elements` according to the number of points and instantiate curves there.

This way I get as many curves at each point as there are points in the mesh.

Then I calculate an index for the endpoints, with which I can query and transfer the positions of the opposite mesh.

This works because the node `Duplicate Elements` does not multiply the individual points beforehand as a whole and line them up one after the other, but always duplicates them point by point.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Awesome! Thank you a lot @quellenform for your answer and attached Blender file, have learn a lot!

Comment: Thank you @quellenform
 for brilliant solving the question!